# Announcing a server connection to client automatically TCP/IP Python

Tags: python, tcp, server, client

I'm currently trying to announce when the client initially connects to the server and to print out a simple message like "you are connected". Its my first program with python so i'm sure they're many easier ways to do what i've accomplished and i'm open to tips

The server successfully responds to the commands "HELO" "REQIP" "REQDATE" "REQTIME" "ECHO" and "BYE"

Here is my tcp server

```
import socket
import time
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 8008

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(1)
c, addr = s.accept()
def Main():
    #print("Server Listening")
    while True:
            data = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if not data:
                    break
            if data =='HELO':
                    Hello(data)
            elif data == 'REQTIME':
                    REQTIME(data)
            elif data == 'REQDATE':
                    REQDATE(data)
            elif data == 'REQIP':
                    IP(data)
            elif data =='BYE':
                    BYE()
            elif data[:4] == 'ECHO': 
                    ECHO(data)
            else:
                    message = ("Invalid command")
                    c.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

def Hello(data):
    if data !='HELO':
            message = ("Server: 510 Sorry i can not service your request. \n Connection Closed")
            c.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
            c.close()

    message = ("Server: 210 Hello " + host + " pleased to meet you.")
    c.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
    Main()

def REQTIME(data):
    if data !='REQTIME':
            message = ("Server: 520 Sorry, time is not available right now")
            c.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

    message = ("Server: 220 " + (time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
    c.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
    Main()

def REQDATE(data):
    if data !='REQDATE':
            message =("Server: 530 Sorry, date is not available right now")
            c.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

    message = ("Server: 230 " +  (time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")))
    c.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
    Main()

def ECHO(data):
    if data[:4] !='ECHO':
            message =("Server: 5350 Cant seem to echo")
            c.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

    text = ("Server: 240 " )
    message = text + data[4:]
    c.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
    Main()

def IP(data):
    if data !='REQIP':
            message = ("Server: 550 Sorry i can not get your IP Address.")

    message =("Server: 250 " + host)
    c.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
    Main()


def BYE():           
    message =("Server: 600 See Ya Later!")
    c.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

My tcp client

```
import socket
def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 8008
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host, port))
    message = input("->")
    myint = 0
    while message != 'EXIT':
            s.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
            data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            print(data)
            if (message == 'BYE'):
                    break
            message = input("->")
    s.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your server just add after the "accept()" a  c.send("your message").

And in your client add a recv() and print() after s.connect((host, port)).

But I don't like the start of your program in the server part. When you start the server, it is waiting a new connection with the "listen" and after the connection it's going in the main function. Maybe you can change that and put your global part in the main function.